# How can I say "to put on/to play some music"?

Tags: translation, music

Basically I'd like to say something like "Should I put on some music?" or "Should I play some music (from my phone)?" and I'm not sure which verb to use.
On jisho.org I found 掛ける {かける} but I'm not sure if 音楽を掛けましょうか。is a correct way to say this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with a phrase such as 音楽を掛けましょうか。 It isn't wrong but it is pretty broad. It works, though, if the type of music, artist, or song don't matter.

In more explicit cases, you could substitute 音楽 for something else. For example:

> 音楽を掛けましょうか。
>   Shall I play some music (from a device)?

...can be changed to something like this:

> 宇多田ヒカルの曲を掛けましょうか。
>   Shall I play songs by Hikaru Utada?

To contrast, if you were talking about playing music on an instrument as opposed to, say, a radio or phone or other such device, the verb could be 弾く (piano, general) or 引く (string instruments, etc.) or another such verb, as opposed to 掛ける.

Comment: Shouldn't it be with a question mark?

Comment: Using the か particle marks that this is a question -- a question mark isn't necessary. Japanese people may sometimes still use question marks, but in this case they really would be superfluous.